# pexpect and sending an "Enter Key" issues

Tags: python, python-2.7, pexpect

I am using pexpect with python 2.7. I am currently writing a script to login to a jump server and then subsequently login to some cisco devices to perform some operations in an automated way.

There is a stage during the login process, where I need to send just a blank line by pressing 'Enter/Return' on the keyboard. After reading many of the posts and other forums, I have tried the following:

```
<handler>.sendline()
<handler>.sendline('')
<handler>.send('\013')
```

However, none of these seem to work for me. When I do login manually to the server and attempt to hit Enter/Return, I see a "C" on the screen and the login process proceeds forward.

I am not sure what the "C" means, however if anyone can help or provide some insight here, it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`.sendline()` is equivalent to `.sendline('')` that is equivalent to `.send('') + .send(self.linesep)` that is likely has the same effect as `.send('\n')` (`'\n' == '\012'`, `'\r' == '\015'`). You could also try `.send('\r\n')` (I'm not sure who is responsible for the terminal line discipline).

Comment: @NarayananSeshan does `.send('\r')` work in your case? what is the application/protocol? Is it telnet? BTW, you should post your comment as an answer

Comment: Nope the .send('\r') did not work. The only thing that did work was .sendcontrol('m').

Answer (score 0):

sendline() should be work.
You can refer to the implementation of pxssh in pexpect.
https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/blob/master/pexpect/pxssh.py